# Python: How to find special value in special lane?

Tags: python

I asked about it yesterday, and some1 gave me a great answer.

But I need to ask one more question.

```
[

Average monthly temperatures in Dubuque, Iowa,

January 1964 through december 1975, n=144

24.7    25.7    30.6    47.5    62.9    68.5    73.7    67.9    61.1    48.5    39.6    20.0

16.1    19.1    24.2    45.4    61.3    66.5    72.1    68.4    60.2    50.9    37.4    31.1

10.4    21.6    37.4    44.7    53.2    68.0    73.7    68.2    60.7    50.2    37.2    24.6

21.5    14.7    35.0    48.3    54.0    68.2    69.6    65.7    60.8    49.1    33.2    26.0

19.1    20.6    40.2    50.0    55.3    67.7    70.7    70.3    60.6    50.7    35.8    20.7

14.0    24.1    29.4    46.6    58.6    62.2    72.1    71.7    61.9    47.6    34.2    20.4

8.4     19.0    31.4    48.7    61.6    68.1    72.2    70.6    62.5    52.7    36.7    23.8

11.2    20.0    29.6    47.7    55.8    73.2    68.0    67.1    64.9    57.1    37.6    27.7

13.4    17.2    30.8    43.7    62.3    66.4    70.2    71.6    62.1    46.0    32.7    17.3

22.5    25.7    42.3    45.2    55.5    68.9    72.3    72.3    62.5    55.6    38.0    20.4

17.6    20.5    34.2    49.2    54.8    63.8    74.0    67.1    57.7    50.8    36.8    25.5

20.4    19.6    24.6    41.3    61.8    68.5    72.0    71.1    57.3    52.5    40.6    26.2

]
```

that's what i got from website, and i used this

```
for line in mystr.split('\n'):
if not line:
    continue
print (line.split()[3])enter code here
```

when i use this, i got every fourth value in every line.

That's almost I want, but if i print it, i also get "in" and "december"

how can I get rid of this two words?

Answer (score 1):

Skip the first two lines.

```
text = iter(mystr.split('\n'))
next(text)
next(text)
for line in text:
   ...
```

...

```
for line in itertools.islice(mystr.split('\n'), 2, None):
   ...
```

Comment: Thanks so much! that's what I exactly want!

Answer (score 1):

Getting something that should be a `float` but isn't is certainly a `ValueError` `exception` try the following

```
 for line in mystr.split('\n'):
     if not line:
         continue
     try:
         print (float(line.split()[3]))
     except ValueError:
         pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `print (line.split()[3])enter code here` with:

```
if line.split()[3] not in ['in', 'december']:
    print (line.split()[3])
```

or, more generic:

```
value = line.split(3)
try:
    value = float(value)
    print value
except ValueError:
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

It is good to use generators in such case, where you can use `try: ... except:...`. My take would be:

```
txt = """[
Average monthly temperatures in Dubuque, Iowa,
January 1964 through december 1975, n=144
24.7    25.7    30.6    47.5    62.9    68.5
16.1    19.1    24.2    45.4    61.3    66.5
10.4    21.6    37.4    44.7    53.2    68.0"""

def my_numbers(txt):
    for line in txt.splitlines():
        try:
            yield float(line.split()[3])
        except (ValueError, IndexError): 
        # if conversion fails or not enough tokens in line
            continue

result = list(my_numbers(txt))
print result # output: [47.5, 45.4, 44.7]
```